# Can I override a request for a class and use a subclass instead if properties are appropriate?

Tags: python, object

Let's say I have two classes with the following interface:

```
class RegularPolygon:
    def __init__(self, sides, length):
        self.sides = sides
        self.length = length
    def area(self):
        '''algorithm for calculating area of any regular polygon using math.tan'''
class Square(RegularPolygon):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(4, length)
    def area(self):
        return self.length ** 2
```

I want `RegularPolygon(4, 5).area()` to return exactly 25 by using `Square`'s `area` function instead of `RegularPolygon`'s. Is there a way to do this, having `RegularPolygon(4, 5)` actually return a `Square` object?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a factory function instead, such as `make_polygon(sides, length)` that checks the value of `sides` in order to decide whether to return a `RegularPolygon` or `Square` object?

Comment: @chepner Yes, but I'd still be curious if what I'm describing is possible.

Comment: It seems like it should be. `RegularPolygon.__new__` could return a `Square` object; the problem is that creating a `Square` object calls `RegularPolygon.__new__` again, so I'm not sure yet how, or if, you can pass the right arguments and avoid infinite recursion.